# Bridging eth0 and vboxnet0 and using ISC DHCP server to provide dynamic IPs

Tags: virtualbox, dhcp, network-bridge

I have Lubuntu 12.04 (64bit) with VirtualBox 4.2 installed and the setup below:

1. `eth0` adapter connected to LAN (having static IP `192.168.0.1` and it is the default gateway).
2. ISC DHCP server listening on `eth0`, to configure PCs (in LAN) with dynamic IPs.
3. `ppp0` adapter (wirless Mblaze USB modem) to connect to Internet.
4. `eth0` has NATed to `ppp0`, so that all PCs connected to the LAN can have Internet.
5. `vboxnet0` host only network (selected for the Virtual Machines).

[image: Setup before bridging]

**I would like to have a bridge combining `vboxnet0` and `eth0` to make it a single network (say `br0`) and have the DHCP server serve IPs through this new bridge. `br0` now should take the static IP of `eth0`, so that the bridge can be the new gateway.**

Please note I neither need Bridged Adapter nor NAT solution in VirtualBox setting UI. I would like to configure all these manually editing all the associated configuration files.

Any help deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed. For anyone interested please see the details below.

1. Install bridge-utils.
2. `sudo leafpad /etc/network/interfaces`

   ```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.0.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   dns-nameservers 10.228.129.113 10.228.129.114
   ```
3. `sudo leafpad /etc/rc.d/rc.local`

   ```
   vboxmanage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet0 --ip 192.168.0.3 --netmask 255.255.255.0

   brctl addbr br0

   ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 down
   ifconfig vboxnet0 0.0.0.0 down

   brctl addif br0 eth0
   brctl addif br0 vboxnet0

   ifconfig eth0 up
   ifconfig vboxnet0 up
   ifconfig br0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

   /sbin/iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
   /sbin/iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface br0 -j ACCEPT
   /sbin/iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE

   restart isc-dhcp-server

   exit 0
   ```
4. `sudo leafpad /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`

   ```
   INTERFACES="br0 eth0"
   ```
5. Restart your computer